# @JSAccessible does not work with JRuby objects?

Tags: jruby, jxbrowser

I use JRuby with jxBrowser.  I´ve just upgraded to version 6.8 and my application stopped working.  I think the problem comes with the new @JSAccessible annotation.  JRuby does not allow method annotation and I inject a JRuby class into a javascript.  What used to work now gives me the following message:

Unhandled Java exception: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.JSFunctionException: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set_this' of undefined

Is it possible to not require the @JSAccessible annotation and bring back the functioning of version 6.7?

Answer (score 0):

To bring back functionality of version 6.7 you just need to avoid using the @JSAccessible annotation in your code. This annotation represents an extension to the current API. If you don't use this annotation, the behavior is the same as in previous versions.

Comment: Thanks... it works fine!  And also, getting back the injected java object also works great!  This was really a feature I was waiting for... thanks a lot!